# integration in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

How would I solve the following equation for ZV:

```
ZV = integral_{0}^{ZD}(z.*A)dz
```

where

```
ZD = 40; 
z = [1:2:12];%depth 
A = [112,118,123,143,188,200];%area
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by your first code-line :( But look at `quad` (http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html), especially have a closer look at the listed examples :)

Comment: sorry, the first line refers to the integral from 0 to ZD and then the first set of brackets refers to the values needed integrating with respect to dz (partial z). Hard to write these without using the symbols.

Comment: But why do you give us values `z = [1:2:12];%depth`? I mean, you are integrating by using `dz` and thus `z` will be your integrating variable and will get values from `0` to `40` :) Yes this can be done quite easily by using `quad` which I linked. Hope that helps!